# How can screen sharing (current tab) be performed without prompting screen sharing dialog box in chrome extension in manifest V3?

Tags: javascript, capture, getusermedia, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, get-display-media

Here, I am utilizing the **getDisplayMedia** and **getUserMedia** APIs to capture both audio and video from the microphone and system in separate streams. Additionally, I am utilizing APIs for real-time transcription with diarization.

However, the challenge lies in recording the screen without displaying a screen sharing dialog box for user consent.

I have observed certain Chrome extensions, such as Tactiq and Airgram, that enable screen sharing without prompting the screen sharing dialog box in the Chrome extension when on google meet.

I have utilized two APIs for capturing audio and video from both the system and microphone, combining them into a single stream. This combined stream is then sent to the Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API for real-time transcription with diarization and other functionalities.

However, my requirement is to record the screen without triggering the 'screen sharing dialog box'. Specifically, I aim to capture the screen while simultaneously capturing microphone audio, all within a Chrome extension using Manifest V3, without the need for user interaction to grant screen sharing permissions.

Comment: `without the need for user interaction to grant screen sharing permissions` that sounds like a very bad idea. So basic you want to capture someone screen without their knowledge or accept?

Comment: I understand and I respect your reply , but I want to obtain all the necessary permissions from the user when the extension starts so that I won't need to ask for permission again later. This way, I can record the screen without displaying the screen sharing dialog box 

When the extension starts, I want to take all the permissions at the same time so that no screen sharing is required later. And start recording without permission.

Comment: Those extensions do it via chrome.tabCapture API judging by their code.

Comment: chrome.tabCapture.capture API does not work in background script and content script. 

Do you have any ideas about APIs for capturing audio from the system and microphone without displaying the screen sharing dialog box in a Chrome extension using manifest V3?